# How to handle requests in a small-medium perl project

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I'm going to start my first perl project which is going to be a simple record tracking system.

I plan to use template toolkit for rendering views with data and individual perl modules to handle things like reporting and database queries, hopefully getting a basic OOP style application going.

My confusion is: how should I handle requests? Should I have a routes.pl file, where I can listen for *all* GET/POST requests and based on those requests, call the appropriate .pm method and return a TT template, basically acting like a front controller? (I come from the PHP framework world, if that helps to understand my viewpoint)

Comment: If this is a web project, use a framework like [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/), [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/). Personally, I use Dancer, which is very lightweight and easy to get a basic application running with.

Comment: Since you are familiar with web frameworks you could do a lot worse than learn to use one of [`Catalyst`](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst), [`Dancer`](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer), or [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I would consider a framework, but this is for a workplace, and I'm a junior dev (hope you get the picture :P)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that frameworks can't be used in the workplace (I'm being facetious, of course they *can* and *are* used by many successful companies). If your boss insists on you reinventing wheels, of course, there's not much you can do about that.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot thanks for your pity (not being sarcastic)

Answer (score 3):

Simple things rarely stay simple, so you should not go the route of rolling your own dispatcher. You'll be reinventing wheels which others have already long solved. And, by going with a framework you're also getting a lot of extra functionality for free, usually through plug-ins.

Have a look at the various Perl frameworks, the ones I can readily think of:

`Dancer` (http://www.perldancer.org/)

`Mojolicious` (http://mojolicio.us/)

`Mason + Poet` (http://www.masonhq.com/)

`Catalyst` (http://www.catalystframework.org/)

I only have experience with `Mason + Poet` and `Catalyst`, though `Catalyst` is far from simple.

Comment: which would be recommended for a perl beginner? i'll have to pitch this idea it seems

Comment: Of these, Dancer is possibly the easiest to get started with and sounds like a good match for what you need it for. But I have no personal experience with it.

Comment: ya i was looking through it, seems pretty similar to Laravel, will check it out. thanks for your input

Comment: Personally, I prefer Catalyst, but it does require installing roughly 50% of CPAN. One of the advantages of Mojolicious is that it's pretty much self-contained, and doesn't have dependencies much beyond core perl, if any.